# Django-crispy-forms AttributeError when using built in AuthenticationForm

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to use django-crispy-forms to display the built-in `AuthenticationForm` with the login view in django. I'm having issues subclassing AuthenticationForm - I'm getting an AttributeError. The error says `'WSGIrequest' object has no attribute 'get'.` Here is my form:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('username', placeholder="username"),
            Field('password', placeholder="password"),)
        super(AuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I think this error has to do with the login view being called via get from a redirect (I'm using the `@login_required` decorator). Does anyone have any ideas on how to subclass built in forms with django-crispy-forms and avoid this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you've got an error in your form:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('username', placeholder="username"),
            Field('password', placeholder="password"),
        )
```

You are calling super, passing parent class `AuthenticationForm` not `LoginForm`.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple I was overlooking! Thanks for catching that...my headache has now gone away :-)

Comment: Glad it helped you :) BTW, usually it's a good practice to call parent method as soon as possible. crispy-forms docs have been updated to show this.